# How to fix cache problem with angular application in google chrome

Tags: angular, google-chrome, browser-cache

I need your help.

I have an Angular application (v17) hosted on AWS where I use S3 to store the files and use ClouFront to distribute them.

I have suffered a constant problem with some users where parts of my application have texts changed automatically and some components stop working correctly, such as some dropdowns (I use PrimeNg as a component library).

This problem mostly occurs in Chrome and only in normal browsing, it does not occur in the incognito tab.

For some users, after clearing the cache, the problem is resolved, but for some others the problem persists. It seems that when I press CTRL + F5 on the page to clear the cache I see the text being displayed correctly and after a few milliseconds it returns to being displayed incorrectly.

The strangest thing is that this happens even with new users who are accessing the application for the first time, it does not necessarily have to be after the release of a new version of the application.

I know that during the production build files are given a unique hash to deal with these caching issues, but index.html is not.
Could it have something to do with this?

I've already invalidated the CloudFront cache, but it still doesn't help.

Has anyone been through this and can give me a direction to follow?